# Extracting script from an SVGScriptElement

Tags: javascript, clojurescript

As `<script>` tags are not executed when inserted into the DOM dynamically, I have to execute them manually by pulling out the scripts from the DOM and calling `eval`.

This works fine with regular `HTMLScriptElement`s, which have the `.text` property available to access the script. However, I've hit a wall trying to access the scripts inside an SVG tag, which are `SVGScriptElement`s which do not have the `.text` property. How can I access the raw scripts within an SVG tag and evaluate them, or indeed is there any better way to do this?

(I think that JQuery is able to do this for me, so it must be possible – although I can't use JQuery directly here)

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is to pull out the nodes directly and use the `.wholeText` property.

```
script.childNodes.length > 0 ? script.childNodes[0].wholeText : ""
```

This will work for both HTML and SVG script elements.